# Touch keyboard doesn't toggle between numeric and text when a html input is selected in kioks mode edge

Tags: keyboard, microsoft-edge, kiosk-mode, kiosk

I'm runnin a windows 10 machine in kiosk mode with edge full screen, and the web app uses 2 types of input, numeric and text.

When the numeric one is selected the touch keyboard should toggle to numeric but this doent's happend.

In the same machin running a non kiosk account works even in full screen, then the kiosk mode is enabled the touch keyboard doesn't toggle any more.

this is the target in shorcut of edge to start in kisko mode:

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Edge\Application\msedge.exe" --kiosk mysite.com --edge-kiosk-type=fullscreen

How can I make it to toggle automaticlly?